# OS X software RAID 0 with 6x SATA SSD?

Tags: macos, performance, storage, raid

I will be able to use a former video editing "Mac Pro" `:)` for a bit, free to configure anything I want in software.

I would like to experiment with setting up OS X software RAID 0 with 6x SATA SSD.

No data reliability required, I will have to relinquish the box after a few tests.

Is this the very best I can get from the storage layer of this machine? Does it make sense to RAID 0 6x SSD drives? Will I be able to install OS X on the software-striped logical volume?

If you have theoretical arguments in favour or against, please explain your rationale. If you have practical experience with OS X software RAID with no parity, that would be ideal!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that 6 SSDs can provide more bandwidth than the [SouthBridge Controller on the MacPro](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/Mac_Pro_0608/Articles/M43_0906_arch.html) can support [(maybe 8Gbit/s or 1GB/s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates)? This may also depend on the model of MacPro that you're using.

The throughput supported by the drives themselves may also come into play...Some SSDs achieve reads of about 250MB/s, while others support rates around 480-500MB/s. Your 3Gb/s SATA ports will probably top out at 375MB/s

My money's on a benchmark of about 1GB/sec for your 6xSSD RAID-0 volume's read rates...Probably a little less for writes...You can probably attain the same speed by striping 3 or 4 drives together.

You can definitely install OS X on this striped volume, but you may not be able to put the recovery partition onto that drive.

Regardless, the AJA Kona System Test is a good utility to use for this benchmarking. I'd be interested to hear what you find.

Comment: I have since been discouraged to RAID-0 those drives.. I never run a proper benchmark on them though. I should have, as you said. I can confirm installation on the striped drive works.